# Angular 5 - Format text in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, markup

I'm trying to add markup from my Typescript file. Here's what I'm trying:

```
textString = `<b>This</b> should be bold`;
parser = new DOMParser();
parsedHTML = this.parser.parseFromString(this.textString, 'text/html');
```

and I'm spitting it back out with `{{parsedHTML}}` in HTML side but all I'm getting back is `[object HTMLDocument]`.

---

How would I display a formatted string in an *ngFor loop?

**Typescript**

```
textString = `<b>This</b> should be bold`;

  planBundle = [
    'One month ($4.99)',
    `One year ($47.90 - 20% Discount)`,
    this.textString
  ];
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <mat-radio-group layout="vertical" [(ngModel)]="selectedPlan">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let plan of planBundle" [value]="plan" style="display: block; margin-top: 8px;">
      {{plan}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

**Current Output**

[image]

---

Could you add inline CSS into this? It doesn't seem to be showing up. Here's what I'm trying:

**Typescript**

```
 planYearTextString = `One year payment <s>($59.88)</s> <b>$47.90</b> <span style="color: green;">(Save 20%)</span>`;

  planBundle = [
    'One month ($4.99)',
    this.planYearTextString
  ];
```

Output

[image]

Comment: parsedHTML.body.innerHTML

Comment: That finally displays my content, thanks. But I'm getting the unformatted text `<b>This</b> should be bold`. How can I format this properly?

Comment: <div [innerHtml]="yourVariable"></div>

Comment: Actually, do you know how I would do this inside an *ngFor loop? I edited my question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same principle, you need to use innerHtml

```
<div>
  <mat-radio-group layout="vertical" [(ngModel)]="selectedPlan">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let plan of planBundle" [value]="plan" 
style="display: block; margin-top: 8px;">
     <span [innerHtml]="plan"></span>
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also add some inline CSS into this? I modified my question again :)

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about css. Anyway, people here will help you if you are stuck with something, but not do everything for you. Especially with css, where "nice" is not an accurate requirement (I could change these buttons to bright pink oval shapes, but you light not find it 'nice')

Answer (score 0):

As per David's comment, the solution to get formatted text into the template is:

`<div [innerHtml]="textString"></div>`